# Integration tests Spring Boot 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, integration-testing

I got bit confused trying to understand what the best way to run integration tests for a Spring Boot 3 rest api application (data jpa,spring mvc). For unit test I use:

```
  @WebMvcTest
  @AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
  class PersonControllerTest {


@MockBean
private PersonService personService;
@MockBean
private SkillService skillService;

@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;


@Test
void whenGetPersonListThenStatusOk() throws Exception {

    PersonListDto personListDto = new PersonListDto(new ArrayList<>());
    when(personService.getAllPersons()).thenReturn(personListDto);
    mockMvc.perform(get(BASE_URL))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().string("{\"persons\":[]}"));

}
```

But for integration test I have no idea what to use. Can I use mockMvc(is it only for unittest)? or Webclient(as I understood is only for reactive app and require jetty)?

So the goal would be to run a real http request involving all application layers and server.

Answer (score 1):

> So the goal would be to run a real http request involving all application layers and server.

For real http requests you can use
`@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)`. This will start your application on random free port and also autoconfigure TestRestTemplate.

`@Autowired private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;`

It is not required to specify the port (nor host) in your test code as it is preconfigured.

`ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange("/api/something", HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);`

Example:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class MyIntegrationTest {

@Autowired private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

@Test
publiс void myTest() {
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange("/api/something", HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);
    // ...
}
```

For WebClient (or WebTestClient) you will need webflux.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Which will also make it available through auto-wiring.
`@Autowired WebTestClient webClient;`. Although you should consider if it is worth adding this dependency just for WebTestClient.

Comment: what is the difference with mockmvc?

Comment: MockMvc is a MOCK. It doesn't start real web server. You can't send real http requests to it.

Comment: So it mocks the server but I guess all the layers like database and service are not mocked

Comment: @WebMvcTest will load your controllers, emulate web requests without actual http calls (mockMvc) and mock other beans (like services), that are required by your controllers.

Comment: As said, if you want "real http request", you commonly use `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)` (or .DEFINED_PORT).

Answer (score 0):

You are 99% of the way there with the test you have.  The key that you're missing is that @WebMvcTest will not create the full spring context that contains your service beans.  I will assume that you're on Junit5, given that you're using Spring 3.  Here's an example of a MockMvc test that will inject actual service instances into your controller.

```
@WebMvcTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) // SpringExtension will spin up the full Spring context
public class PersonController_IT {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    
    @Test
    void whenGetPersonListThenStatusOk() throws Exception {
        PersonListDto personListDto = new PersonListDto(new ArrayList<>());
        mockMvc.perform(get(BASE_URL))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string("{\"persons\":[]}"));

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, so your example is not mocking the service and is actually bringing up all the server? Can we call it an integrationtest?

Comment: You can and should call this an integration test.  I've modified the test class name to reflect this.  Follow the surefire naming convention for integration tests, which is to name them `*IT.java`,  `IT*.java`, or `*ITCase.java`

Comment: > "@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) // SpringExtension will spin up the full Spring context" why not just @SpringBootTest then?

Comment: As pointed out by @ILyaCyclone, there are many ways to achieve what you want :)